# load common template with different content for different pages in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, hubspot

i have created a template called `thank-you.php` and inside that i want to show different content as per the parent url.
for e.g. `mywebsite.com/page/thank-you` and `mywebsite.com/another-page/thank-you`. here, i need to load same template but with different content as per the parent url.
let's say if i submit the form on `mywebsite.com/page`, i need to show video related to `/page` on `mywebsite.com/page/thank-you` and the same procedure for `mywebsite.com/another-page/thank-you` which shows video related to `/another-page`.
`Note`: I need to show this as end result of `hubspot` form submission on different pages.

1. do i need to create a page in admin area for that?
2. do i need to set this page as a child? if so, how can i set as a
   child for specific pages(around 25 pages)?
3. how can i solve this problem?

I am new to wordpress. any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the url and depending on that write different logic or content

```
$url = strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if($url, "/page/")) {
  // Content or logic for mywebsite.com/page/thank-you
} elseif(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "/another-page/")) {
  // Content or logic for mywebsite.com/another-page/thank-you
}
```

Comment: but how can i redirect to `/thank-you` after form submission? and where do i put this code?

Comment: If you will code form handler yourself
then you can add 
    header('Location: your-redirect-url"); .
If we're talking about using some plugin or third-party sercive
then it depends on that plugin/service there are different solutions.
For example there are forms plugins that will do all the work for you
and can show different thank you message for different forms.

Comment: For example you can use Contact Form 7 plus this add-on https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpcf7-redirect/